# Increase LocalStorage on Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a worklight app for Android. We use the JSONStore in order to store around 10MB of data that is required for the application when its disconnected. The front end code is in Angular 2, typescript. When we run "mfp cordova run" and choose the android device we have no issue with the JSONStore. But when it runs in CHROME, ( required for all our testing ) we are getting the 
"DOMException: Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': Setting the value of 'jsonstore.myDatabase' exceeded the quota."

- I have tried the following by using sqlite.
  INSERT INTO HostQuotaTable values ('website','1','10000000');
- The insert works, i can retrieve the row, but the error does not go away.
- There are suggestions about doing it in the "Quota" table, I could never find that table under Chrome , i.e. Appdata///Chrome///Local Storage.
- This is very critical for our testing.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mobile Foundation JSONStore that runs in the web browser does not use a SQLite database, it uses HTML5 LocalStorage which has a 5 MB capacity.
I would either test in an emulator, physical device, or reduce the test data.

Comment: Sir, Thank you very much. Is there anyway to increase this LocalStorage temporarily , at least for that session.

Comment: You can't increase the size of LocalStorage in Chrome, but in Firefox I was able to increase the size by going to [about:config](http://about:config), search for "dom.storage.default_quota" and changing the value in kilobytes.